# Does Go offer a standard or defacto way to deal with errors within a single statement (i.e. inline error handling)?

Tags: go, error-handling

In Rust, the `Result` type, which can be thought of as the `(val, err)` pattern in Go, can be immediately "unwrapped" within the statement it occurs, and without needing the complexity of having multiple lines dedicated to this task. For example, assume we have a function `foo` that returns a number or an error. In Rust, dealing with this error (without ignoring it) can be as simple as:

```rust
let x = foo().unwrap() + 1;
```

In Go, the recommended way to do this seems to be:

```golang
x, err := Foo()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
x = x + 1
```

Does Go offer a *standard* way to deal with errors immediately within a single statement like Rust? Or should I just stick to my own homegrown solution instead?

My ad-hoc solution is:

```golang
func unwrap[T any](val T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        return val
    }
}
```

---

*I'm a bit surprised by the excessive moderation. None of the five questions linked are duplicates and none answer my question specifically. Some even appear to be completely unrelated. I assume this is because of my poorly worded title. I have reworded the title to more inline with my actual question. Thankfully, u/norbjd answered my question adequately.*

Comment: *"Does go offer a standard way to deal with errors immediately within a single statement like Rust?"* -- No, it does not.

Comment: In Rust `unwrap()` is considered a bad practice and should be rare. So maybe it's a good thing Go does not have it. The thing I miss from Rust is the question mark operator, `?`, propagating the error (`if err != nil { return ..., err }`).

Comment: Even if the question is answered, I've voted to reopen this question as 1) it's not a duplicate of the linked links 2) OP has edited his title to be more precise 3) it may be useful for developers coming from Rust or other languages where `unwrap` or similar methods exists in stdlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mkopriva stated in the comment, there is no built-in way to do this in Go. However, you can find this pattern in many libraries under the `Must` denomination:

- in `text/template`: [`Must`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/text/template/helper.go;l=24)
- in `regexp`: [`MustCompile`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/regexp/regexp.go;l=316)
- in `net/netip`: [`MustParseAddr`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/net/netip/netip.go;l=132)
- etc.

There is an [open proposal on Go to add a generic `must.Do` method](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54297), but nothing concrete yet.

The recommended method for now is to define the `Must` method in your code with generics (since Go 1.18), as you've done:

```golang
func Must[T any](v T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return v
}
```

And use it like this:

```golang
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func Foo() (int, error) {
    return 1, nil
}

func Bar() (int, error) {
    return 0, errors.New("some error")
}

func main() {
    foo := Must(Foo())
    fmt.Println(foo)
    bar := Must(Bar()) // this will panic with "some error"
    fmt.Println(bar)
}
```

There are some attempts to create libraries to provide this method, like [`wingyplus/must`](https://github.com/wingyplus/must), but as the repo states, based on Go philosophy:

> A little copying is better than a little dependency.

So it's up to you to either define your own method in each of your projects, or use these kind of libraries, until `Must` is integrated in Go standard library (if it's ever integrated).

Comment: Didn't know that must was a defacto convention. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!